Kubuntu 24.04's Virtual Audio Device for Simultaneous Output disappeared
Since upgrading from Kubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 (KDE Plasma v5.27.11), the option to add or configure a Virtual Audio Device has been missing. I see no more possibility to do so, neither using pavucontrol nor the built-in "Audio" Settings.
Right-Clicking the speaker icon in tray still has an option "Show virtual devices" - I probably have none of those, so checking this box doesn't show any more devices.
Question:
Is there any newer method (or cmdline tool) to create a Simultaneous Audio Output Device?
